# SwiftUI WatchOS: Animation behaves strangely when placed inside a list?

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos, swiftui-animation

I have this pulse animation below which works well by itself, but when I place it inside of a `List` then the animation of the circles pulsing is correct but all of the circles also move vertically from the top to the center of the screen as well?  Outside of a `list` the circles remain in the center.  Why is a `list` causing this and how to get around?

```
import SwiftUI

struct HeartRatePulseView: View {
  @State var animate = false

  @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase

  func circlesColor() -> Color {
    Color.blue
  }

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: -3) {
      ZStack {
        ZStack {
          GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
              Circle().fill(circlesColor().opacity(0.25)).frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height).scaleEffect(self.animate ? 1 : 0.01)
              Circle().fill(circlesColor().opacity(0.35)).frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.79, height: geometry.size.height * 0.79).scaleEffect(self.animate ? 1 : 0.01)
              Circle().fill(circlesColor()).frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.60, height: geometry.size.height * 0.60)
            }
        
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
          }
        }
        .onAppear { self.animate = true }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase, perform: { newValue in
          if newValue == .active {
            self.animate = true
          } else {
            self.animate = false
          }
        })
        .animation(animate ? Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: true) : .default)
    
      }
    }
    .frame(height: 145)
  }
}

struct HeartRatePulseView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    List {
      HeartRatePulseView()
    }
    .listStyle(.carousel)
  }
}
```

Comment: Elaborate more for minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Asperi I removed some of the extra elements I had in there.  If you just drop this `view` in a `list` (even in just a SwiftUI Preview) you will see this behavior.

Comment: This appears to be watchOS, adding a .border(Color.green) shows the ZStack moving completely up and down which seems broken. If you switch to a ScrollView it's fine, maybe a SwiftUI bug?

Comment: @Chris I should have specified yes this is WatchOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if you change the animation method slightly it works,

Note the `value` argument, it seems this is the new way to animate

```
.animation(animate ? Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: true) : nil, value: animate)
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct HeartRatePulseView: View {
  @State var animate = false

  @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase

  func circlesColor() -> Color {
    Color.blue
  }

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: -3) {
      ZStack {
        ZStack {
          GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
              Circle().fill(circlesColor().opacity(0.25)).frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height).scaleEffect(self.animate ? 1 : 0.01)
              Circle().fill(circlesColor().opacity(0.35)).frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.79, height: geometry.size.height * 0.79).scaleEffect(self.animate ? 1 : 0.01)
              Circle().fill(circlesColor()).frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.60, height: geometry.size.height * 0.60)
            }
    
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
          }
        }
        .onAppear { self.animate = true }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase, perform: { newValue in
          if newValue == .active {
            self.animate = true
          } else {
            self.animate = false
          }
        })
        .animation(animate ? Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: true) : nil, value: animate)

      }
    }
    .frame(height: 145)
  }
}

struct HeartRatePulseView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    List {
      HeartRatePulseView()
      HeartRatePulseView()
    }
    .listStyle(.carousel)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I build a demo project to file a bug but also noticed the way I was calling animate was depreciated so i switched to `.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: animate)` which works as well 